# Checking existence of a large file served on localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a file served on a localhost URL like this: `http://localhost:<port>/content/<file>`

Now I have to check the existence of file using JavaScript in my Chrome App. I tried using an AJAX call, but that process is responding extremely slowly as the file size is large.

I just need to check the existence of file — is there a smart way to check that? I'm also new to `FileReader` and not getting the use of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use a `HEAD` request instead of a regular `GET`? That would return all the server headers along with the response status, and without any data beeing sent from the server. If response status is 200 - your file is present on the server, if it's 404 - it is not.

Comment: Yepp that did my job, now I'm able to check existence of 119MB file in a fraction.

Comment: Just a concern, can I use type: "HEAD" when using $http in angular js???

Comment: To be honest, I'm not familiar with Angular, but I'd assume that setting the request type to HEAD should do the job.